# Definite integral as a limit of sum

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following as a limit of sum:

$$\int^b_a{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

We can write it as

$$\lim_{h \to 0;h>0} h\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+2h}}+...\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+(n-1)h}}\right)$$ where $h=\dfrac{b-a}{n}$

I'm not sure how to proceed further.

I also tried to expand everything binomially. It didn't lead to anything.

Comment: I guess you can multiply and divide by $n$, then use Stolz-Cesaro.

Comment: Haven't heard of the theorem before. Just checked brilliant. Not sure how to apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with $a > 0$,

$$\underbrace{h\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{a + kh} + \sqrt{a + (k+1)h}}}_{=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\sqrt{a + (k+1)h} - \sqrt{a + kh}\right)}\leqslant h\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a + kh}} \\\leqslant \frac{h}{\sqrt{a}}+ \underbrace{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{a + kh} + \sqrt{a + (k-1)h}}}_{=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sqrt{a + kh} - \sqrt{a + (k-1)h}\right)}$$

See if you can finish yourself by evaluating the telescoping sums on the LHS and RHS, and then applying the squeeze theorem in taking limits as $h \to 0$.

Comment: It should be easy to see that the limits will be $2 (\sqrt{b}- \sqrt{a})$.

Comment: Why don't you let the sigma of the upper bound be like others?

Comment: That’s fine as well since for small $h$ we have $\sqrt{a-h}$ defined.

Comment: The RHS sum telescopes to $\sqrt{b-h} - \sqrt{a-h}$ with your limits.

Comment: Yeah thanks!. Also what's the intuition for such problems? When do we use sandwich theorem? It doesn't seem obvious here.

Comment: With enough experience and practice you naturally look for bounds where squeezing may help evaluate the limit of a sum.

Comment: In this case the obvious thing to try is bounding the term as $ a_{k+1}+a_k < 2a_k < a_{k-1} +a_k$ since they are decreasing. Seeing the square root you naturally try to multiply and divide by the conjugate and see what happens.